# How to obtain error for functions stream_get_line and fgets?

Tags: php, sockets, error-handling, fgets

I have a code where I open a socket connection. From time to time it happens that [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) returns false. I would like to find out why it happens. Is there a function that would provide more details about last error on `$handle`? Something like `preg_last_error`, `json_last_error`, …

The same question can be applied to function [stream_get_line()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php).

I use PHP 5.4 and `E_ALL` is in error_reporting (i.e. it includes even `E_NOTICE`). No error was thrown.

Comment: It's ridiculous this issue still hasn't been solved internally within PHP's native stream API. Error handling is one of the most important requirements of any framework, regardless of language and purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about stream can be retrieved by using [stream_get_meta_data()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php). However, I solved the issue by rewriting my code to use [socket_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) functions. The API provides [socket_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php) function which helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

NB this is untested code. I haven't got an installation of PHP to try it out on.

You should be able to do this with *contexts*, which you create when you set the connection up.

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params(
    $context, 
    array(
        'notification' => function(
            $notification_code,
            $severity,
            $message,
            $message_code
        ) {
            switch ($notification_code) {
            case: STREAM_NOTIFY_FAILURE
                print_r(array(
                    'message' => $message,
                    'message_code' => $message_code,
                ));
                break;
            }
        },
    )
);

$socket = stream_socket_client ($remote_socket, &$errno, &$errstr, ini_get("default_socket_timeout"), STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

`fgets` should now call the error handler whenever an error occurs.

I'm sorry I can't test this at the moment...

Comment: According to this [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52811) the solution won't work. I have tried it and no notification was triggered.